# why is my state not resetting inside of a function in setInterval and useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const inter = setInterval(() => getData(), 1000);
  }, []);

  async function getData() {
    if (!isLoading) {
      return;
    }

    console.log(isLoading);
    const data = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/todo/')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => data);

    if (Array.isArray(data)) {
      setData(data);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }

  const tododata = data.map((ddd) => {
    return <h1>{ddd.title}</h1>;
  });

  if (isLoading) {
    return <h1>Loading</h1>;
  } else {
    return (
      <>
        {console.log(isLoading)}
        {tododata}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

**code summary**

this is a simplified code from my real project. So I have 2 `useState` and the first one runs once and to try and get data for the first time, and the purpose of the second one is if the first one didn't get the data and the user is stuck in the loading the second one will repeatedly try to get the data and if the frontend gets the data **it should stop fetching**.

**my problem**

in this code somehow the `getData` function will keep fetching indicating that the `isLoading` is true but at the same time the component will render all of the title from the `data` state indicating that the isLoading is false. Why did this happened?

Comment: "Somehow the getData function will keep fetching" - no big wonder, because you have `setInterval(() => getData(), 1000)` which means that `getData()` gets triggered over and over again **every 1000 ms**.

Comment: btw - `.then((data) => data)` is pointless, unless you meant - `.then(({data}) => data)`

Comment: @PeterB Sorry I don't really get this. So because of  `setInterval` it will still use original `isLoading` state which is true and it wont update?

Comment: I made changes to my answer to use `setTimeout` instead of interval. I think that would be a better solution. Also your mistake was the one that Andy mccullough suggested about executing function instead of assigning it.

Comment: @andymccullough I was too stupid to understand that haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change my answer to accommodate to `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  async function getData() {
    if (!isLoading) {
      return;
    }

    console.log(isLoading);
    try {
      const data = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/todo/').then((res) => res.json());

      if (Array.isArray(data)) {
        setData(data);
        setLoading(false);
      } else {
        setTimeout(() => {
          getData();
        }, 1000);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        getData();
      }, 1000);
    }
  }

  const tododata = data.map((ddd) => {
    return <h1>{ddd.title}</h1>;
  });

  if (isLoading) {
    return <h1>Loading</h1>;
  } else {
    return (
      <>
        {console.log(isLoading)}
        {tododata}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tested this by turning off my REST API so the fetch would fail and after I turn it back on it didn't make any request took me a refresh to get the data.

Comment: Ah, yes, that is because error will not continue with code after. I will make change to include try/catch. Take a look. Now it should initiate new call if API throws error.

Comment: you killed it. Thanks